# C#: How to split text block into chunks by fixed boundary?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

Is there any simple way to split a block of text (no matter of form, may by `List<string>` or `string[]` array) in C#? I'm kind of newbie and looking for solution...
Input form is something of:

```
Not important line 1
Not important other line
FIXED BOUNDARY
Line 1 for chunk 1
Line 2 for chunk 1
...
Line n for chunk 1
FIXED BOUNDARY
Line 1 for chunk 2
Line 2 for chunk 2
...
Line n for chunk 2
FIXED BOUNDARY
Line 1 for chunk 3
...
Repeated for end of input lines
```

In the end, I need to get `List<List<string>>` or `List<string[]>` with chunks: each element of list should contains all lines belongs to chunk from 1 to n (including boundary or not: it doesn't matter):

Chunk 1:

```
Line 1 for chunk 1
Line 2 for chunk 1
...
Line n for chunk 1
```

Chunk 2:

```
Line 1 for chunk 2
Line 2 for chunk 2
...
Line n for chunk 2
```

and so on. The number of chunks may vary, so I don't know how many chunks may be in input string list. How should I split it? Is there any library for that kind of text transformation? Please help guys...

Comment: I think answer is no.  You could keep reading lines and add them to a list, until you hit "FIXED BOUNDARY", then start a new list etc.   But there isn't a standard method to do this for you.

Comment: @Neil - Well, he has asked for a simple way and imo that is just what you just described. So my answer is: 'yes'..

Answer (score 0):

Multiple application of String.Split combined with LINQ methods will work:

```
var text = 
@"Not important line 1
Not important other line
FIXED BOUNDARY
Line 1 for chunk 1
Line 2 for chunk 1
...
Line n for chunk 1
FIXED BOUNDARY
Line 1 for chunk 2
Line 2 for chunk 2
...
Line n for chunk 2
FIXED BOUNDARY
Line 1 for chunk 3
...";

List<string[]> parts = text.Split("FIXED BOUNDARY" + Environment.NewLine)
                            .Skip(1)
                            .Select(x => x.Split(Environment.NewLine))
                            .ToList();
```

"FIXED BOUNDARY" is used as separator and not included in result